# What is the screen saver showing animated physics simulations?

Tags: screensaver, animations

A few years ago the computer lab at my university had as a screen saver on their Linux machines with animated simulations of physic laws, like foam bubbles disintegrating exponentially or little circles elastically colliding like ideal gas particles, among others. Each time the screen saver got activated you got to see a randomly provided simulation from the pool. And I think there was a small text saying where you can look up the code for the simulation.

I think this was a screen saver that came preinstalled with the Linux distribution, but I can't find it anywhere. Can anyone tell where I can download it?

Comment: `xscreensaver` has many many options; many are based on science molecules, space.. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xscreensaver

Comment: Could it have been one of the [BOINC projects](https://www.google.com/search?q=boinc+projects+with+graphics) that  had graphics?

Comment: @Jos Unfortunately, it wasn't BOINC :) The animations had a different look every time, and I had myself SETI@Home, so I know it wasn't looking like BOINC

Comment: @guiverc I think it was indeed `xscreensaver`, I tested it and it looks very much like some of the animations I saw, thanks! If you care about reputation, you can write and answer and I will accept it as correct. You can refer to this link, I used it to get `xscreensaver` on my ubuntu: https://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested `xscreensaver` which contains loads of options, some are science based (molecules, space..) with more available optionally.

Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xscreensaver

`xscreensaver` was already installed with my system (lubuntu), but can be added with `sudo apt install xscreensaver` if your release/flavor doesn't include it by default.

You may wish to disable your own screensaver (which can vary on flavor/release).[image], or add additional optional packages which increase your available choices.